# Multiple angular 5 components manipulate one central component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gis, openlayers

I'm currently working on an **Angular 5 GIS project**, which is focused on a central component containing an `openlayers` map. I need basically every other component, to be able to manipulate this map. Thus, i need a clean solution for the other components to invoke functionality in this central component, in order to eg. change position on the map, change layers etc.

I have tried using `@Output/@Input` with `EventEmitter`, which works, but scales horribly as 100's of these events will be required in the end. Is there a way to make a service, which can be injected into every relevant component, which in turn can manage the manipulation of the map component? I have looked at subjects / observables, but have a hard time wrapping my head around whether this is a viable option. The app is expected to become quite large, so i want this to be done right from the very beginning. I know there is a lot of material and posts on this, but haven't found any I feel satisfy this use case.

Any angular wizards with some good advice? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: place the map object in a service, then inject the service into each component. the main component sets the map, while the others fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was faced by facebook hence they came up with flux architecture, you can use Redux with Angular to tackle this issue. It is meant for this specific use case in applications.

Redux allows you to have a single state across application, hence reducing event loops and all.

http://blog.ng-book.com/introduction-to-redux-with-typescript-and-angular-2/

https://www.uruit.com/blog/2017/05/04/using-redux-angular/

https://dzone.com/articles/why-should-you-be-using-redux-with-angular

Comment: Having read your excellent links, it seems like this could be a solution. I'll accept this answer for now, and return with a status ones i have implemented redux and know for certain. Nevertheless an excellent read and a great tool to know about. Thanks!

Comment: @Hjorth pls update me ad well once you implement it. It would be nice to see that. Do you have a GIT repo to share? As I am  looking for a opensource GIS project in Angular 5 with openlayers..